# How do I create a trigger in MariaDB? Currently my attempt causes the console to be stuck

Tags: mysql, triggers, console, mariadb

I have the following tables:

Fruits

[Fruit Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htXvZ.jpg)

Pair

[Pair Table Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4UmU.jpg)

Basically I would like to create a trigger, that when I insert a new fruit that has a sweetness of 5, I would like the rest of the fruits to have their ids paired with this newly inserted fruit added to the pair table.

So example if I were to issue the command, Insert into Fruits values (1006, 'Kiwi', 5);
I would expect the Pair table to be updated as follows,

[Updated Pair Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbUiE.jpg)

I tried to create a trigger with the following code,

```
Delimiter // 
CREATE TRIGGER t1 AFTER INSERT ON fruits 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN 
    IF (sweetness.new=5) THEN
      INSERT into Pair values(id.old,id.new);
    END IF;
  END// 
Delimiter;
```

However, after I tried the above code, my MariaDB console application seems to be stuck, whenever i press enter the -> arrows keep appearing.

[Stuck error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvnfK.jpg)

Any kind soul in the universe Please help!

Comment: You haven't reset the delimiter..

Comment: It's OLD.something not something.OLD

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. We're glad you're here. You will get better responses to your question if you post text, not links to screenshots. This and other tips are in the [Help Center topic on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @P.Salmon how do i reset the delimiter?

Comment: // enter, delimiter ; enter

Comment: BTW there is no OLD. in an insert trigger - you should review the documentation.

Comment: @P.Salmon Nice, i got the delimiter reset. I'm still learning and unsure how to create the right trigger for the desired result. Could you suggest how i should go about in doing so?

Comment: ' I would like the rest of the fruits to have their ids paired with this newly inserted fruit' - but that's not the case in your updated pair table.1002 has dropped out..

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm sorry 1002 should have been included it was a typo on my end. May I know how I can change the trigger creation code to solve this? I would really appreciate the help, been trying for the past few days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could

```
Delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER t AFTER INSERT ON fruits
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
 IF (new.sweetness=5) THEN
   INSERT into Pair 
    SELECT DISTINCT ID,NEW.ID
    FROM FRUITS
    where id <> new.id
    ;
 END IF;
 END //
 
 DELIMITER ;
```

Note the space between the end and the delimiter.